# update records ajax jquery isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a script that can update a status in the database.

My php code is:

```
<?php
include ('../model/incentives.class.php');
$change = new Incentives;
$change_status = $change->change_status($_GET['id'], $_GET['status']);
?>
```

this works, (i tested it without ajax)

my ajax is:

```
function change_status(id, status) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:('control/change_status.control.php'),
        data: 'id='+id+'&status='+status,
        cache: false,
    })
window.location.reload(true);
}
```

and i call the function with

```
<a href="javascript:change_function(1, 0);">Change Status</a>
```

But this won't work. is there anybody who knows how to fix this ?

thx!

Comment: is this generating an error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your window.location.reload in the success callback of your Ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:('control/change_status.control.php'),
        data: 'id='+id+'&status='+status,
        cache: false,
        success:function(data){window.location.reload(true);}
});
```

Otherwise that reload will run at the same time your Ajax call is made and because of the reload the Ajax call will be interrupted.

Also make sure you dont finish the Ajax properties with a comma. You had:

```
{ 
type: 'GET',
url:('control/change_status.control.php'),
data: 'id='+id+'&status='+status,
cache: false,
}
```

The comma after false should not be there, if there are no other properties following the cache property.

Comment: Ok, i did that, and now it can update the status from 0 to 1, but not from 1 to 0?

Comment: I think that has to do with your HTML after you reload the page the `<a href="javascript:change_status(1, 0);">Change Status</a>` is not changed to `<a href="javascript:change_status(1, 1);">Change Status</a>`

Comment: Well what I understand is that you try to toggle the status between 0 and 1. If you say that it updates from 0 to 1 but not the other way around then the only possible problem is the way your function gets called (wrong parameters) or your PHP isn't receiving the right info.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it works now, i wrote "succes" instead of "success".

Comment: Could you except the answer please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `<a href="javascript:change_function(1, 0);">Change Status</a>` when the function in javascript is called `function change_status(id, status)`
So just change `<a href="javascript:change_function(1, 0);">Change Status</a>` to '`<a href="javascript:change_status(1, 0);">Change Status</a>`

Comment: oops, i made a type in the question ... but in my code here it is the right call

Answer (score 0):

I guess replace below

```
data: 'id='+id+'&status='+status
```

with

```
data: { id: id, status: status}
```

will sort out your issue.

Comment: This makes it easier to read and debug but has no end-effect on passing the parameters via a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets try this:

For the PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include ('../model/incentives.class.php');
$change = new Incentives;
$change_status = $change->change_status($_GET['id'], $_GET['status']);
if ($change_status) {
   echo "true";
} else {
   echo "false"
}
?>
```

Json:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:('control/change_status.control.php'),
        data: 'id='+id+'&status='+status,
        cache: false,
        success:function(data){
           if (data == "true") {
            alert('reload');
            //when this message comes up, use the window.reload thingy
           } else {
            alert('no reload');
           }
        }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `success:function(data){alert(data)}`? Does that return something? If not the page gets called but can't read it. Most likely because of a false return code (no json, 404, 500, 501, etc)

Comment: ofcourse your PHP Scripts needs to echo something (echo "OK")

Comment: it returns true or false

Comment: in text or in PHP boolean?